# Save user inputs as a character vector in R

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Is there a way to store user inputs (textInput) as a character vector to be used later in the program? Say if the user inputs are - FB, AAPL, AMZN, NFLX, GOOGL - I want them to be stored something as

user_inputs <- c("FB", "AAPL", "AMZN", "NFLX", "GOOGL")

Sorry but my code below just errors out. I have trying to get this done for the last 2 hours and any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput('vec1', 'Enter a vector (comma delimited)')
  verbatimTextOutput("mytxt")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  Output$mytxt <- renderPrint{
    for (i in input$vec1){
      i
    } 
  } 
  
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**EDIT** I want to use it inside shiny.

Comment: Check out the shinyWidgets package: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/shinyWidgets/versions/0.6.2  After you install the package you can load the library and then launch the shiny widgets gallery: library(shinyWidgets); shinyWidgetsGallery()  That will load examples of every widget in an independent window.  If the values you are collecting from the user are fixed, they can be pre-loaded into a multi-choice picker widget for user selection.  The Gallery is very useful for collecting user inputs generally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, as Tim pointed out you have many errors in your Shiny code, unrelated to splitting a string into a character vector.  In particular, you need to separate lines inside `fluidPage` with commas, `output` should not be capitalized, and a function like renderPrint should use `()` and not `{}`.

Always start with working code as a template before adding your own logic.  That makes it much easier to find where your real problem is.

I use Tim's answer to split the string.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    textInput('vec1', 'Enter a vector (comma delimited)'),
    verbatimTextOutput("mytxt")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$mytxt <- renderPrint(strsplit(input$vec1, ",\\s*")[[1]])
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `strsplit` on the CSV input:

```r
input <- "FB, AAPL, AMZN, NFLX, GOOGL"
output <- strsplit(input, ",\\s*")[[1]]
output

[1] "FB"    "AAPL"  "AMZN"  "NFLX"  "GOOGL"
```

Comment: library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput('vec1', 'Enter a vector (comma delimited)',
            "FB, AAPL, AMZN, NFLX, GOOGL"),
  verbatimTextOutput("mytxt")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  Output$mytxt <- renderPrint{
    strsplit(input$vec1, ",\\s*")[[1]]
    }}

shinyApp(ui, server)

Comment: Tried to do this but it did not work.

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: it errors out. The code that I posted in my comment above.  I need to use it within Shiny,Sir.

Comment: You have some other problem(s) in your code, not related to my answer.